# CSS site navigation menu disappears on IE7 and IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

Could someone explain why this menu disappears on IE7 and 8 please? It works fine on Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Safari. Page width also get changed on IE7 and the 3 column area in the middle becomes a 2 column area. [Here is the site link](http://www.wecare.eu.com/wecare/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glanced at your site and style.css

It looks as though line 187 is the problem

You have this:

```
li#menu-item-29 a, ul#mainmenu-menu li.menu-item-29 a:hover {
    background-image: url("http://wecare.eu.com/images/btnHome.gif");
}
```

Remove the :hover pseudo class here and just leave **a** { ...

And regarding the 3 column breaking on the central part it is because IE7 does not support box-sizing CSS3 attribute. So you have set the width to 33.3% + padding of 15px left and right for the each of the columns. On newer browsers it works cause the box-sizing: border-box calculates the box size differently.

The solution for this would be to create a conditional statement for IE7 & 8 stylesheet and calculate the width differently. My suggestions is set it something like this:

```
width: 29.333%
padding: 0 2% 20px
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the input but the background image didn't work even after I removed the pseudo class. Besides that class is important to generate that effect. While trying your suggestion, I cleaned up the CSS as I noticed some issues. IE7 and 8 issue remains the same, and in addition to that, effects are no longer working on Chrome and Safari. Any suggestions? Despite my short question, I did try my best to find a solution for this but going no where. All I want is to replicate the menu effect on [here](http://www.wecare.eu.com/)

Comment: Please ignore my previous comment. You were right. I think it was the :hover pseudo class which was causing the problem. Managed to get it working on all except IE7. At least now I can see those images on IE7 too so I guess it is a matter of positioning them correctly.